Pytest: Mocking requests.get to Raise RequestException for 400 Error
I’m writing tests for a currency converter application using pytest. I want to test the scenario where the API returns a 400 error. However, my test is failing because the expected requests.exceptions.RequestException is not being raised. Here is my code:
import datetime

import pytest
import requests
from src.currency_converter import (convert_currency, get_exchange_rate,
                                    humanize_time)

mock_response_json = {
        "rates": {
            "EUR": 0.85,
            "USD": 1.0,
        },
        "time_last_updated": int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    }


class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, mock_response_json, status_code):
        self.mock_response_json = mock_response_json
        self.status_code = status_code

    def raise_for_status(self):
        if self.status_code >= 400:
            raise requests.exceptions.RequestException(f"{self.status_code} Error")

    def json(self):
        print('json')
        return self.mock_response_json

@pytest.fixture
def mock_response_success(monkeypatch):
    def mock_get(*args, **kwargs):
        mock_obj = MockResponse(mock_response_json, 200)
        return mock_obj

    monkeypatch.setattr('requests.get', mock_get)

# Test for get_exchange_rate function with a successful API call
def test_get_exchange_rate_success(mock_response_success):

    exchange_rate, time_last_updated = get_exchange_rate('USD', 'EUR')
    
    assert exchange_rate == 0.85
    assert isinstance(time_last_updated, int)


# # Test for get_exchange_rate function with a currency not found
def test_get_exchange_rate_currency_not_found(mock_response_success):

    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="Currency 'IRR' not found in the API response."):
        print('ValueError')
        get_exchange_rate('USD', 'IRR')

def test_get_exchange_rate_currency_not_response(monkeypatch):
    print('mock_response_failure')

    def mock_get_reqerror(*args, **kwargs):
        return MockResponse(mock_response_json, 400)
    monkeypatch.setattr('requests.get', mock_get_reqerror)

    with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.RequestException, match="400 Error"):
        get_exchange_rate('USD', 'EUR')

When I run the test, I get the following error:
E       Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'requests.exceptions.RequestException'>

I noticed that the third test, which fails, actually passes if I comment out the first and second tests. This suggests that there might be test leakage, where the state from the previous tests affects the third test. It seems that the mocking process is not being applied correctly in the third test.
